# Simple 3 letter day in PHP

Tags: php

I know that getting the last 3 letters of the current day goes like this: `echo date(D);` but how do I get tomorrows and the day after that, I tried something like this: `echo date(D)+1;` but it doesn't work :(

Comment: Your typo is making me laugh. The last 3 letters of any day would be 'day' :)

Comment: The only I want to know is who are those 2 persons who favored this question.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Try:

```
echo date('D', strtotime('+1 day'));
```

etc.

Comment: I'd prefer robust manual solution from Shah over this lazy magic.

Comment: @YourCommonSense I'd prefer to get the result and move on with my life

Answer (score 3):

You'll need to make time using mktime() function. Something like this

```
$tomorrow = mktime(0,0,0,date("m"),date("d")+1,date("Y"));
echo "Tomorrow is ".date('D', $tomorrow);
```

Syntax for mktime():

mktime(hour,minute,second,month,day,year,is_dst)

Answer (score 2):

Tomorrows 3 letter day

```
echo date('D', strtotime('+1 day'));
```

Day after that 3 letter day

```
echo date('D', strtotime('+2 days'));
```

Comment: This is inaccurate way